# Add additional data to JSON response in ListCreateAPIView

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class ItemListView(ListCreateAPIView):
    model = Item
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer # model serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.all()

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is there any chance to add additional data to JSON response in `get` method?

Answer (score 2):

You could override `ItemSerializer`'s `to_representation()` method, as

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # your fields

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance).copy()
        data.update({"key": "value"})
        return data
```

Answer (score 0):

```
response = self.list(..)
response.data['hello'] = 'world'
return response
```